# How to update order field's value sequentially for specified multiple id only?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have following table in MySQL.

```
id | aname | orderNum | parentId
1  | A     | 2        | 1
2  | B     | 1        | 1
3  | C     | 4        | 2
4  | D     | 1        | 2
5  | E     | 3        | 2
6  | F     | 2        | 2
7  | G     | 3        | 1
```

I want to update `orderNum` field for following:

```
Set orderNum=1 when id=3 and parentId = 2    
Set orderNum=2 when id=7 and parentId = 2        
Set orderNum=3 when id=5 and parentId = 2        
Set orderNum=4 when id=6 and parentId = 2
```

In short I would like to set orderNum in increment order for ids (3,7,5,6). I will receive id in (3,7,5,6) order and then I want to update orderNum field in same sequence.

Can anybody help? How can I create an Update query for this?

I want to do this with MySQL.

**Note: please see updated question**

Comment: So orderNUM equals id?

Comment: @strawberry no. It's just an example. I'd can be in any sequence

Comment: It's a lousy example. In that case, see CASE!

Answer (score 1):

here is the sql query to do what you want.

```
Update TABLENAME set `orderNum`= `id`;
```

Comment: If id are different for each increment for 'orderNum'?

Answer (score 1):

Use [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) to get the index of the `id` in our sequence of `id`s

```
update your_table
set ordernum = field(id, 3,7,5,6) 
where id in (3,7,5,6)
and parentId = 2
```

Comment: If id are different for each increment for 'orderNum'?

Comment: How order by id would help? Id could be in any order and there could be so many other records

Comment: If `id` is irrelevant, why mention it in your question. What are you trying to achieve? Please add example data and expected output to your question.

Comment: Thanks again for your effort and solution. Before few mins I also came with same solution except use of FIELD(). Only problem I am facing is that it updating orderNum field with incremental order but with ascending order of ids specified. Like it first picks up 3,5,6 and 7 but not (3,7,5,6) :(